How do I integrate the redirect to okta login flow with capacitor without leaving the mobileapp?
I have a working website that uses okta's redirect login flow, ie the user gets redirected to an okta login page and then back to the web app. I'm trying to convert the website into a mobile app using capacitor, a main challenge is that when logging in or out the redirect opens a browser window to function. This kind of ruins the in-app experience because different devices could have different default browsers that act differently, sometimes asking which app to use. Capacitor has an in-app browser that can be used and might solve this issue, but I'm not sure how to configure Okta to let me call the redirects using the in-app browser.
(same question at Okta support)
How can I integrate the okta redirect login flow with capacitor's in-app browser?

Care to explain the close vote?  What could possibly be wrong with this question?
